# ¿Como resolver en un estado hijo el primer elemento de un listado resulelto en un estado padre?

Tags: angular, angular5

Buen dia.

Tengo un estado padre en el cual resuelvo un listado, este se carga mediante una peticion http.

Este estado padre tiene un hijo el cual debe resolver el primer elemento del listado padre.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Como podria soluicionar esta situacion?
De antemano gracias

Answer (score 0):

Podrías probar utilizando la propiedad *parent* de *route* de la siguiente manera dentro de los hijos:

```
ngOnInit() {
this.route.parent.data.subscribe(data => {
    this.project = data.residents;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo solucione cargando en el servicio de resolve hijo los datos del resolve del estado padre

```
@Injectable() export class OnlyUserResolve implements Resolve<User>{ resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot) { return route.parent.data.users[0];}}
```